# Add an title attribute to every td of a table based on a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hava 2 tables

```
 <table class="first">
    <thead>
          <th> header1</td>
          <th> header2 </th>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>hi</td>
                <td>hello</td>
           </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>


 <table class="second">
    <thead>
          <th> header1</td>
          <th> header2 </th>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>hi</td>
                <td>hello</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>hi</td>
                <td>hello</td>
           </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

now my jquery Part:

```
  var trainingInstanceIds = ${trainingInstance.id};
  alert(trainingInstanceIds) // which prints say 1,9,
```

now i want every td of second table to have the title as the value given in trainingInstanceIds

basically i want something like this

```
   <table class="second">
    <thead>
          <th> header1</td>
          <th> header2 </th>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td title="1">hi</td>
                <td title="9">hello</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td  title="1">hi</td>
                <td  title="9">hello</td>
           </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

the value of trainingInstanceIds  and the number of td will change .

here i want to add title to an already created table

how to do it?

```
    $.each(trainingInstanceIds, function(index, value) { 

   });
```

Comment: If its dynamically created, can you do it in the code that generates the table in the first place?

Comment: i want to add title for an already created table

Answer (score 3):

You could just pass a function to jQuery's `attr`-method:

```
var trainingInstanceArray = [1, 9]; 
// OR use if it's a string:
var trainingInstanceArray = trainingInstanceIds.split(',')
$('.second td').attr('title', function (index, attr) {
    return trainingInstanceArray[$(this).index()];
});​
```

[Example at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wXcfs/)

Comment: The better and simpliest solution

Answer (score 2):

It might yield better performance to iterate over the `td`s instead of the ids:

```
var trainingInstanceArray = trainingInstanceIds.split(',');

$('.second td').each(function(index, element) {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.attr('title', trainingInstanceArray[$el.index()]);
});
```

**Edit:** I missed that you wanted every title for every row. Updated above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if trainingInstanceIds is coming as an array.

```
$.each(trainingInstanceIds, function(index, value) {
    $('.second td:eq('+ index+')').prop('title', value);
});
```

or use if trainingInstanceIds  coming as string

```
$.each(trainingInstanceIds.split(','), function(index, value) {
    $('.second td:eq('+ index+')').prop('title', value);
});
```

and Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/95z6d/3/)**

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object 1,9 has no method 'split'

Comment: trainingInstanceIds is coming as string, or an object

Comment: check updated answer, but what `trainingInstance.id` is returning? a string value, an array or if an object then what is its structure.

Comment: In your demo, you take the html with the title.

Answer (score 1):

```
// I suppose that trainingInstanceIds is a table
$.each( $("table.second tbody tr"), function(){
    var tds = $(this).find("td");
    $.each(trainingInstanceIds, function(index, value) {
       $(tds[index]).attr("title", value);
    });
});
```

I think something like this. But you assume attribute title is not w3c compliant.

Comment: it does not add title to dynamically added tds

Comment: but works for regular tds, not working for dynamically added tds

Comment: if you replace $.each(tr, ... with $.each('table.second tbody tr', .. it should work on dynamically added.

Comment: and I suppose that trainingInstanceIds is table I edit and comment.

Comment: For dynamic td I think you put this code in function and call this function each time you update the table.